# Fixing wall with constant moisture over the years

Tags: repair, walls, humidity

I live in Mexico where most of the houses are made by brick and cement. Over the years we have had moisture in the walls as shown in the images below.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, it looks like if the wall is falling apart. Even in some parts of the walls with this problem, we don't even have pipelines where it could be a potential water leaking. We have checked and we don't have any of those.

We have hired several masons to fix it and we have bought a lot of different chemicals and very powerful acids that eat the cement of the wall in order to kill the moisture but we have not succeeded, yet.

[image]

My dad told me that long time ago people used to put big chunks of charcoal in vases that sucked all the moisture from the wall but it seems that is a very old way to do it and the house would not look pretty with vases all over the house.

Is there a way or method you know in how to fix this for a long period of time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to participate here. What's on the other side of the wall? Is it above grade or below grade?

Comment: FYI, humidity is vapor in the air. You have liquid moisture, either condensed _from_ humidity or seeping through from some other source. The latter is more likely from what I see. I'd start by checking for roof leaks and groundwater sources.

Comment: Are your masons working on the inside or outside? I have found many try to cure very similar problems by working on the inside, most fail. Sealing the outside and preventing moisture from entering in the first place would be your best bet. I have had good results with 2 part epoxy on acid etched floors stopping moisture entry but have only limited results on walls. This may be because the epoxy seals better on horizontal surfaces, verticals surfaces may take several coatings off they ever seal on the inside. I have also seen some thick latex paints that would seal the outside, Worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

I deal with excessive moisture in the house by using a portable dehumidifier. I live up in the Seattle area where we get a LOT of moisture. A side effect is that it creates heat from both the electricity used and that water vapor needs to release heat to condensate (the opposite of steam from heated water); this a positive in the winter (free heat from the water vapor) and a negative in the summer.

[image]